# MySQL return inverse? Results of a search or results NOT containing

Tags: mysql, select, key, where-clause

A complex one here? (for me at least). I have a table called `tickets`, with the `id` column being the unique key. I have another table called `Labels`, which doesn't have a unique key (from the looks of it). In `Tickets` we store ticket information (messages, who made the ticket etc). We can add a label to a ticket when we create it so that we can search for tickets with those labels e.g. "review later".

What I am trying to do, is a reverse type query e.g. show me all tickets that don't have a specific label associated with it e.g. Don't show me any tickets with "review later". IF A TICKET DOESN'T HAVE ANY LABELS NOTHING IS PUT IN THE LABEL TABLE. I just can't get any type of query I write, by hand or with a query builder to work.

I'm my image, you can see `Tickets.id` has 174 against it, which is also shown in `Labels.ticket_id 174` with 2 x Labels set against it.

[image]

No matter what query, join, does, does not, etc I try, I either get back no results OR for some strange reason, I still get `ticket 174` showing up.

Here is the most simple query I have tried... However, I think I've tried about 30 iterations by now from simple to very complex.

```
SELECT tickets.id
FROM
  tickets, labels_tickets
WHERE
  tickets.id <> labels_tickets.ticket_id
GROUP BY
  tickets.id
```

Can anyone suggest why this wouldn't work or think of any method to build a statement that says:

Show me all tickets.id from tickets that don't have the label "MyLabel" or doesn't have a value at all in the Labels table.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT tickets.id 
    FROM 
      tickets 
    WHERE 
      tickets.id NOT IN (SELECT ticket_id from labels_tickets where labels_tickets.label = 'out of hours' or labels_tickets.label = null) 
    GROUP BY 
      tickets.id
```

Try this I  think it will work.

Comment: Ill give that a go too! Thankyou... this has been driving me nuts for hours now!

Comment: If `labels_tickes.ticket_id` contains `NULL` values this will return incorrect results. If that is possible, then a `where ticket_id is not null` should be added to the sub-select.

Comment: This seems to be working. Ive changed the query above to reflect one of my labels and also the null value! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `outer join` and select only the tickets where no `ticket_id` is found in the `labels_tickets` table.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM tickets t
LEFT OUTER JOIN labels_tickets l ON t.id = l.ticket_id
WHERE l.ticket_id IS NULL
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING sum(l.label = 'review later') = 0
```

See [this JOIN examples](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I think.. from the looks of it.. that worked! And I tried a left outer join and searched for null too! Im going to run some tests and I will get back accept as answer if alls going well!! Thankyou!

Comment: This is close! it does return all tickets that arent listed in the "Labels" table... but doesnt give me the option to filter on a keyword within the label database e.g. "review later".. Im now thinking how to add in an AND or OR or something to do that?

Comment: Hi Juergen. Im still not having any luck, but its possible Ive re-written your query incorrectly, so Ive posted my take on your query above. The query does run, but returns 0 results.

Comment: Managed to get it working with Abu's answer. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The following gets all tickets that do not have a ReviewLater label:

```
SELECT lt.ticket_id
FROM labels_tickets
group by lt.ticket_id
having sum(case when label = 'ReviewLater' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This treats all the labels as a group.  The sum counts the number that have the desired label.  You want the ones where this count is 0.

I strongly recommend using a `group by` and `having` for such set-membership type queries.  It generalized easily to arbitrary combinations of the presence or absence of tags.

Comment: Managed to get it working with Abu's answer. Many thanks for your help!